# strcat() is duplicating its second parameter

Tags: c, string

Self-teaching C is full of surprises. I do this short snippet to test `strcat()`, which supposedly appends the second parameter to the first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char s1[4] = "Foo ";
char s2[] = "Bar";

int main(void) {

    strcat(s1, s2);

    printf("%s %d %d \n", s1, strlen(s1), strlen(s2));
    return 0; 
}
```

I was expecting some overflow error since `s1` is an array of 4 chars, but instead I got this:

```
Foo BarBar BarBar 10 6
```

I did this on Windows using MS Visual Studio Express 2013 (which by the way raise some alerts about using strcat). So... why did strcat duplicate the value of s2? That's not in the documentation.

Comment: An overflow can cause many different behaviours. The language doesn't specify what happens after an overflow. It's undefined behaviour. Anything can happen!

Comment: you have to understand that C has a model as simple as possible. you have to adapt the world without exceptions first.

Comment: the standard specifies that writing over the boundaries of an array is `undefined behaviour`. Also printf the result of strlen with `%d` is `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: BTW: `printf("%s %d %d \n", s1, strlen(s1), strlen(s2));` should be `printf("%s %zu %zu\n", s1, strlen(s1), strlen(s2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
char s1[4] = "Foo ";
```

creates a character sequence `s1` without a zero-terminator. That means that `s1` is not a string and it is illegal to pass it to `strcat`. The behavior is undefined.

(In the above declaration with initialization you are using an obscure feature of C language, which allows zero-terminator to "fall off" the end of the char array being initialized. In C++ this initialization would be ill-formed, since the initializer string requires a buffer of size 5, not 4.)

In practice this causes `strcat` to run over the end of `s1` array and into `s2` (apparently accidentally located nearby in memory) looking for zero-terminator in the first argument. So in the end you are adding `s2` to a combination of `s1+s2` in memory, which creates the effect of `s2` getting duplicated. Needless to say, the result is meaningless.

Of course, even with `s1` of size 5 the code would still exhibit undefined behavior, since there's no room in the target buffer for the result of concatenation. Size of `s1` must be at least 8 for the result to fit into it.

Answer (score 0):

first: s1 is not null-terminated

second: you're allocating static memory for s1 and s2. the compiler usually packs those into a shared data-block of your executable. if you're reading over the boundary of s1 you're reading into this block, since your programme 'owns' this memory, the OS won't complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that a C string is "null terminated" - that is it ends at a null byte ("\0") (and hence cannot contain multiple null bytes). So the string "Foo " is actually *five* characters long `{'F', 'o', 'o', ' ', '\0'}`.

You define a 4 character array and fill it with *five* elements.
`char s1[4] = "Foo ";`
This means the next array, `s2`, which is likely put next to the first one, will overwrite the null byte of `s1`.

Because C strings are defined up to the null byte, `strcat` will copy characters from the first string until it reaches the nullbyte. But, because `s2` overwrote the null byte, the first null encountered by `strcat` is the null from `s2`.
So from the point of view of `strcat`, `s1` looks like `"Foo Bar\0"`;

Comment: "define a 4 character array and fill it with five elements. char s1[4] = "Foo "; ... " is not correct.  Only the first 4 elements are put in `s1`.

Comment: True; the "fifth" element is actually part of `s1`.

Comment: To be clear, the 5th element of `"Foo "` is not put anywhere.  Neither in `s1` nor `s2`.

Comment: Oops, I meant _not_ part of `s1`.